# After build React app showing blank page. How to solve this problem?

Tags: reactjs, build, create-react-app

In my react app when I run it in local then working fine and the home page and all other routing pages working fine.

After build it and run it showing a blank page in the browser and showing some errors in the console.

**Error**

```
Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at Vs (react-dom.production.min.js:280)
    at react-dom.production.min.js:149
    at Ri (react-dom.production.min.js:176)
    at Bu (react-dom.production.min.js:271)
    at js (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at Es (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at ks (react-dom.production.min.js:250)
    at vs (react-dom.production.min.js:243)
    at fs (react-dom.production.min.js:237)
    at Xs (react-dom.production.min.js:285)
```

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "binks-admin-dashboard",
  "homepage": "./",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "array-move": "^3.0.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
    "react-bootstrap-table-next": "^4.0.3",
    "react-bootstrap-table2-paginator": "^2.1.2",
    "react-date-range": "^1.1.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-grid-gallery": "^0.5.5",
    "react-icons": "^4.1.0",
    "react-image-picker": "^1.1.1",
    "react-images-upload": "^1.2.8",
    "react-images-uploader": "^1.2.0-rc1",
    "react-images-uploading": "^3.1.2",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "react-select": "^4.0.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.27.14",
    "react-sortable-hoc": "^1.11.0",
    "react-widgets": "^5.0.0-beta.22",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
  }
}
```

How to find this error and solve the problem?

Comment: Are you using create react app? What's the build command in your Package.json.

Comment: @SanishJoseph I added the package.json file above plz see it once

Comment: How are you running the production build after the build?  Using "serve -s build"?

Comment: @SanishJoseph  build command I used- `npm run-script build ` and for after build `serve -s build` So yes your right

Comment: Try removing the homepage option from Package.json. Let me know the result.

Comment: Tried it but no effect, same issue  @SanishJoseph

Comment: What are the errors in the console and network tab in the browser? You may paste it as part of your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227934/discussion-between-yuvraj-and-sanish-joseph).